# SSH Time out Error

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I am looking for new ideas on how can I do more better.

Home laptop (home Laptop can access only Linux VM)
Linux VM (This machine can access only jump box)
jump box VM

I can ssh fine from Linux VM to jump box keys are setup.

one user is set up in Linux VM called joe and Joe .bash_profile looks like this.

```
ssh 10.0.0.1 || ssh 10.0.0.2
```

Note: There is two nic on jump box if one is down we can use the other nic for login.

Let's say first nic is down and when I do `telnet` from my home laptop (`telnet` Linux VM) and provide user name joe it should automatically connect us to `10.0.0.1` but one is down it's giving message timeout and taking a long time to connect to other nic.

is there any way when I do telnet and give user name check first ssh connection if down automatically connects to other second one like in 2-3 secs?

Right now it will give us a message

```
time out 
time out 
time out
```

And then it will try to connect the second nic.

I can more clarify if you guys have any more questions for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
ssh -o 'ConnectTimeout 1' 10.0.0.1 || ssh -o 'ConnectTimeout 1' 10.0.0.2
```

or

```
{ nc -z -w 1 10.0.0.1 22 && ssh 10.0.0.1; } || { nc -z -w 1 10.0.0.2 22 && ssh 10.0.0.2; }
```

Comment: Thanks, ill give a try..